# Use Laravel's Config class inside of app.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've created a single, custom config file (`config/myconfig.php` for example's sake) so anyone can easily change options quickly in **one** place to work in their particular environment with configurable options.

I've had success getting these config keys working in some files (my controllers and even in database.php). However, it seems like I cannot use the Config class in app.php. For example I'd like to set `'debug' => Config::get('myconfig.debug_enabled')` but I keep getting an error: `Class 'Config' not found`.

Maybe I'm just missing something or just have the wrong approach. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the app.php config, the facade aliases have not been loaded yet (they're contained in the app.php file). If you add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` to the top (after `<?php`), you'll be able to use `Config::get()`.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel published a global `app()` function, which gives you access to the IoC container, so you can do:

```
app()->make('config')->get('database.default')
```

This one just worked for me inside `app.php`.